# Adding custom column in the output with awk

Tags: shell

I am reading file utilization on the server with below command.
How can I add the hostname in my output as a first column?

Thanks in advance

```
df -h | grep % | awk '{OFS="\t";print $6,$5}'
```

Output:

```
/apps/inf9b2b  43%
/apps/dbclients        13%
/apps/inf9     77%
```

Comment: As an aside, on some platforms (and maybe some locale settings on platforms on others) the column names contain a `%`, so `grep %` or its awk equivalent won't necessarily serve their presumed purpose of filtering out the header. Perhaps you should filter on line number, not by looking for a `%` sign? With my answer, that would mean changing `/%/` to `NR>1`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple application of [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

```
df -h | awk -v hostname="$(hostname)" '/%/ {OFS="\t"; print hostname, $6, $5}'
```

Note that there's no need for an external `grep` -- just make your pattern match a condition of the awk statement.

Comment: CNR -- please be certain you copied it *exactly* as given. See this code running in the virtual machine at https://ideone.com/hC7m1I -- no syntax error there.

Comment: ...you'll see that it's including the header line there, but that's because their header uses a `%` sign; changing it to `NR>1` instead of `/%/` would avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `df -h | grep % | awk '{OFS="\t";print "hostname\t" $6,$5}'`

Comment: hostname        /dev/odm        0% <br/>
hostname        /apps   79% <br/> This it how it looks like now